# How do I view 2 apps as a multitasking Split View on an iPad Air 2 running iOS 9?

Tags: ipad, multitasking, ios

I've updated an iPad Air 2 to iOS 9 and can get the the Slide Over view to come out by swiping from right to left on the right hand side of the screen, but there does not seem to be a divider on the left side of the app that slides out that would allow me to stretch the app to take up 50% of the screen instead of 33% like I've seen in other iOS 9 multitasking videos.

I tried a mixture of the built in Apple apps (Notes, iBooks, Safari, Calendar, News) but none of them seem to have the ability to be stretched to take up 50% of the screen.

I double checked in the settings that the General > Multitasking > Allow Multiple Apps is set to on as well as Persistent Video Overlay (which does seem to be working as I can play video over the top of other apps).

Is there other settings I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **for sure** an iPad Air **2**, correct? It should have TouchID (a fingerprint sensor) on the front.

To verify the model, go to the settings app, General, About:

- Model MH2P2LL/A is an iPad Air 2

Other ways to identify your iPad are at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201471

Comment: Oops, wrong iPad. Didn't even think to look for the TouchID. Can't believe I spaced that. Thanks.